# Registry key cannot be created in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, even if program is elevated

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

This little piece of code below is run as an elevated process.

`RegCreateKeyExW` returns the error code 5 (Access denied) because it cannot create the registry key for some reason.

**More facts:**

- If I replace `".cre"` with e.g `".cyr"` the key is created without problems.
- **Actually all keys starting with `".cr"` have the same problem. IOW I can create keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, provided they don't start with `".cr"`**
- I can create the `".cre"` key (and any other keys starting with `".cr"`) manually in the Registry editor without problems.
- on my other computer there is no issue with this
- Both computers are running Windows 10.
- the program is run from an elevated command prompt (which has been launched via the Windows menu while maintaining <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed) and it it definitely elevated.
- prior to running the code snippet I made sure that the ".cre" key doesn't exist elsewhere in the registry.
- the code is compiled as 64 bit program.

```
  DWORD disposition = 0xffffffff;
  HKEY hkey = 0;
  LSTATUS result =  RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L".cre", NULL,
                                    NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL,
                                    &hkey, &disposition);
  std::cout << "Result = " << result << "\n";
  std::cout << "Disposition = " << disposition << "\n";
```

I also tried writing into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` like this:

```
LSTATUS result = RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Classes\\.cre", NULL,
                                 NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL,
                                 &hkey, &disposition);
```

But the results are exactly the same (as I expected).

I have absolutely no clue what is going on here.

Comment: Are you a system adminitstrator (or debugger user) on one and a regular user on the other? Not all elevations are the same

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's run via an elevated cmd prompt (see edited question)

Comment: 2 things: (1) make sure you are looking at the right registry see [WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details). (2) run `regedit` see [View the system registry by using 64-bit versions of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/view-system-registry-with-64-bit-windows) right click the key in question and check `permissiions...`

Comment: And you might need to check a MS-Windows application started from an elevated command prompt also runs elevated.

Comment: HKCR is a view of different things (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/hkey-classes-root-key). Maybe the key exists somehow, you might want to check virtualization for example with this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization?redirectedfrom=MSDN#controlling-registry-virtualization

Comment: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a merged view of two branches, one under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and one under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. HKLM is the default if the key you're trying to create doesn't already exist. So administrator permissions are *normally* needed to write to HKCU. The exception is when the key already exists under `HKCU`.

Comment: @RichardCritten (1) `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is reflected by `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`, Im' not sure how this could be an issue here. (2) initially the ".cre" key does not exist, so it's pointless to check it's permissions. When I create the ".cre" key manually with regedit, it's permissions are no different from the permissions of any other key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Comment: @RichardCritten the application launched from the elevated cmd prompt is actually also elevated as my litte code snippet is able to create keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` provided they don't start with ".cr", see the first 2 items under "More facts" in the question. If I launch it from a normal non elevated cmd prompt it not able to create _any_ key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` which is expected behaviour.

Comment: @SimonMourier the virtualisation stuff might be a thing, I will check this tomorrow. OTOH prior to running the code snippet I made sure that the ".cre" key doesn't exist elsewhere in the registry.

Comment: I just compiled your code and ran it in an elevated command prompt window. It worked fine and successfully created a `.cre` key.  It does get "error 5" in a non-elevated prompt.  **Are you sure your code is running from an elevated command window** ?

Comment: @selbie yes, It also works fine on my other computer. And yes the cmd prompt is definitely elevated and I definitely can create keys, provided they don't start with ".cr". Read the "More facts" section where everything is explained in details. I know it sounds crazy...

Comment: @JonathanPotter the code snippet is definitely running as elevated process, so creating keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` should be no problem. I edited the "More facts" section in the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @SimonMourier having read again the [Registry virtualisation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-virtualization?redirectedfrom=MSDN#controlling-registry-virtualization), I think this is not an issue, because the program is running elevated, so virtualisation doesn't apply, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky - Hmm not 100% sure :-) ... Another idea, have you tried to use Procmon from sysinternals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon and filter on registry events, maybe it'll give you some insights on that problem.